# How can I publish an ASP.Net Core Web Api to HTTP instead of HTTPS in development?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm a newbie in web apis and I'm trying to develop an ASP.Net Core Web Api. So far I can see that IIS Express publishes my web api on https by default. Can I somehow change this? I want to publish it on http for testing purposes. The default certificate that it generates it's useless because it's generated with localhost as it's DNS, so when you import it on another machine it doesn't help with anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you actually accessing a web app hosted in IISExpress from machines other than where your app is actually running? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1. You can check your startup and see if you have below line:**

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

If it is present comment it.

**Step 2:**

WHile publishing to IIS, do not select HTTPS protocol.

These two steps would be sufficient.

[image: Please check this image for knowing where HTTP is configured]

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to avoid using IIS Manager. I got it working modifying launchSettings.json. It's enough to remove the sslPort from there and remove the https application url.

Comment: Glad I could help.